# OpenFOAM, PETSc or other sparse matrix multiplication source code

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Could someone tell me, where I can find source code for matrix multiplication realized by OpenFOAM,  PETSc or something similar? It can't be trivial algorithm.
I have found homepages of OpenFOAM and PETSc but in doc I cant find multiply methods and source code.

Answer (score 1):

PETSc implements matrix multiplication for many formats, look at this part of [MatMult_SeqAIJ](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-as/snapshots/petsc-dev/src/mat/impls/aij/seq/aij.c.html#line1108) for the most basic implementation. For a sparse matrix stored in compressed sparse row form with row starts `ai`, column indices `aj`, and entries `aa`, multiplication consists of the following simple kernel.

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
  y[i] = 0;
  for (j=ai[i]; j<ai[i+1]; j++)
    y[i] += aa[j] * x[aj[j]];
}
```